# Check user from request in Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have my own Web Services (Jersey java ) and Tomcat 7. Now , for debugging I want to allow  access to the WS only if the user is present in a database , otherwise Tomcat rejects the request, is possible this via Tomcat configuration ?

Because the alternative is every API in my WS check this user if is present in db or not.

Thanks

Comment: How can you get the "user" from request? By some ID or token or...?

Comment: for example the user request have some parameters, and one parameter is IMEI, i have database with this IMEI, Tomcat can take this parameter IMEI from request? and check in the db? or if possible only via WS?

Comment: Check this for Jersey secutiry https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html

Comment: ok, so with i must work in the WS..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if such custom validation is exist in Jersy
i am posting this, in case no such thing is exist,

it's mostly like a -if i were you- suggestions,

so, i have 2 options here i may try to work on:

**1- Adding a Filter:** this will filter all requests, to the API url,
right there in `doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException` you could check any validation you need, based on the validation result you can let the request pass, or respond with some error message, [check this](http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial#servlet-filter) for a sample

then declare that class as `servlet-filter` in `web.xml` on a url higher than `ServletContainer` url,

**2- Extending ServletContainer:** (`com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`)
as we know this class is configured in `web.xml` to handle all incoming requests then forwarded to the proper endpoint class and method, so extending this class, with a custom container, ex, `MyServletContainer` in the new class, just override the method `doFilter()` and do the same as above
in case of validation error, respond with some error, in case of pass, just call `super.doFilter(...)` check [this link](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html#doFilter(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain)) for Jersy ServletContainer info

then at `web.xml` just configure the new class as the container

example for extending ServletContainer:

```
public class MyServletContainer extends com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer{

    @override
    public void doFilter(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response,
                 javax.servlet.FilterChain chain)
          throws java.io.IOException,
                 javax.servlet.ServletException {

                //get param from request
                //connect to DB or any cache system to validate the param value

                //if validation fail: do something like this [NOT TESTED NEED SOME TRY and ERROR...]
                if(!dataSrc.isValidUser(paramValue)){
                    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                    out.println("{"status":"fail","message":"invalie user info"}");
                    out.flush();//maybe ...
                }else {
                    //validation is OK, so keep doing what original ServletContainer (super) should do
                    super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
                 }
    }//doFilter() --end

}//CLASS
```

these options provides a validation process on requests without implementing it in all end-points.

**again** i am not sure about those options, just thoughts that may help someone :)

good luck